# Finding the name of a special key, and then where to change it's mapping (with xkb..)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've a new Travelmate TM645 with a special weird key: the right Shift key is made smaller and adjacent is a key that (for me) gives a "\" or "|".
That key is annoying for me, since I hit it often together/instead of the shift key.
Now I've found some good info on [xkb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) on changing the mapping, but guess: two questions:

1. how do I find the name of the key?
   /usr/share/X11/symbols/pc shows for example
   "key  { [ XF86KbdLightOnOff ] };" which I recognize,
   but so far no trace of that special key..
2. then probably too; where how to change it to do the same as "modifier_map shift"

thanks!
Cor

Comment: Someone mentioned 'xev'
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xev1.html
So next step: find in which file to change this

Answer (score 1):

So this is solved as follows:
command `xev` resulted in output that showed `keycode 94 (keysym 0x5c, backslash)` for the key I want to change.
Changing in one of the files in `:/usr/share/X11/xkb/` is an option, but will be reverted on system updates, so I choose to just change it on statup of the system with xmodemap:
    xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = Shift_L"
I'll add that to a script for/at statup, obviously.